# How can I trigger a function for the input checkbox in the headerComponentParams

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am using Angular Ag-Grid and having this problem:

```
colDefs = {
    ....
    { field: 'This field', editable: false, sortable: false, width: 90,
      type: 'stringColumn', centered: true, pinned: 'left',
      headerComponentParams: {
        template:
          '<div class="lmn-form-group">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" value="" (checked)="clickedUse($event)">' +
          '<span>Good?</span>' +
          '</div>'
      }
    },
    ....
 }

clickedUse($event) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

Basically I am embedding a check box in the header of column, but upon checking the clickedUse is never reached. I tried (change), (checked) and (click), but none is working.
What am I missing? Does headerComponentParams support trigger of events?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML Event Attributes instead of Angular Event bindings, i.e. `onclick` instead of `(click)`.

Replace `(checked)` with `onclick`:

```
'<input type="checkbox" value="" onclick="clickedUse($event)">'
```

Comment: This looks very promising. There are still some issues. First, if I use clickedUse($event), then I have "Uncaught ReferenceError: clickedUse is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick". Second, if I use this.clickedUse($event), then I have "Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined". Third, if I use this.clickedUse(), then I have "Uncaught TypeError: this.clickedUse is not a function". Fourth, if I use clickedUse(), it says clickedUse is undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's possible, I'd recommend using Custom Header Components instead: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-header/